# Normalizing binary representation of floating point - not IEEE standard

Tags: binary

A recent question on the Cambridge A level exam asked students to write a bit pattern that was in  unnormalised form  (float)  into normalized form.

Show the bit pattern in normal form:

mantissa                           exponent

00110000                           00001011

This one I got correct:

Mantissa                       exponent

0110000                        00001010

The mantissa is now normalised  as the the first two bits are different.
I shifted the bit in the mantissa left the  exponent goes up by a power of two from 2 to the power 8 to 2 to the power 10

OK, this one I can't figure ut and I am not alone.

The next question we were asked to do the same, but I cannot figure out how the answer (given below) was derived!

Question - convert the unnormalised bit patter for a float to a normalised one.

Mantissa                       exponent

11100011                       00110011

This was normalised to:

Mantissa                      Exponent

10001100                      00110001?

It said no one got this correct! Can anyone explained how this was normalised bit patter was derived. It is not IEEE so no bias is used.

Answer (score 0):

The un-normalized bit pattern is 1.1100011 | 00110011

In order to normalize it, you need the first two bits to be opposite, i.e. 1 and 0 or vise versa.

so you move the imaginary decimal point to the place where there are opposite bits.

111.00011 | 00110011

Make them the first two bits and make it an 8 bits representation and change the exponent to the number of places you moved the imaginary decimal point.

1.0001100 | 00110001

So the final answer is 10001100 | 00110001

This is a method that I use in order to answer such questions.